# Is there a way to separate audit activities from "real" actvitites in a case?

Tags: civicase, activities, activity

In the "Activities" section of case management, real to-do items are mixed with the audit activities that are recorded for documentation purposes. This is irritating to some users.

Has anybody found a way to separate these audit activities from the "real" activities of the case (i.e. the ones originating from user entry , a sequence or a standard timeline)? In my opinion, the ideal solution would be to separate the audit trail and show it in a separate tab or different section of the screen, since you usually only need to look into these activities, if anything goes wrong during the processing of the case. 
Completely deactivating the activities is not a sensible solution either, because the audit trail might be needed and very helpful in managing critical or disputable cases.

Answer (score 1):

I had one site where they asked me to have it automatically put the "copy sent to" activities into the trash, so they're still there but don't show unless you use the filter accordion to see them. It's not efficient database-wise, but for low volume is a possibility. At the time extensions didn't exist yet, or maybe were just starting, so it was implemented by overriding a core file. You might be able to do something similar with hook_civicrm_post, and while not robust, the subject lines are mostly identifiable so could filter based on that and set is_deleted=1.

Comment: It's not so much about the notifications, because for one of our customers they are entirely switched off anyway. It's more about the presentation in the GUI

Comment: Ok but I mean you can use the same technique for the other ones. The notifications are just one example.

Comment: Hm, not sure, I really want to do that. They might be accidentally deleted. And then you will lose the audit trail.

Comment: Fair enough. There's an accordion at the top of the case activities list on manage case labelled "search filters" that lets you see them. But I understand the concern that subject-matching isn't a perfect way to identify them.

Answer (score 1):

We had build a extension years ago that groups the activities created by standard timeline into a section and the activities added manually into another. But we didn't manage it to differentiate or exclude these activities while printing audit report. Things have changed a lot in CiviCRM since then allowing hooks to change the behaviour and how data is stored in db. So its possible to do it with implementation of GUI hooks.

Comment: I'll check that out, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Latest news on this: A useful CiviCase extension has undergone some major changes and improvements. See the section "Activity Categories" in this link: https://civicrm.org/blog/jamienovick/civicase-new-way-manage-cases-using-civicrm

Has anybody tried it, yet?

Comment: There's a slight variation of that extension you can look at at https://dcase.demo.civicrm.org. I've looked at both versions of the extension before and I'm not sure it's exactly what you're looking for, but check it out. It still shows activities like "Change Case Status" alongside Followup etc.