# How can I access an activity's grouping value in CiviCases?

Tags: civicase, activity

I've only started trying to change some features of an existing CiviCRM database in a testsystem (using CiviCases). So I am still a beginner, I excuse myself if this is a silly question, and any hint will be appreciated :)

I want to include a feature that will exclude all the activities with the grouping value "system" from the case view. Right now, the case view is spammed with activities not relevant to the users (for example, "Case type changed from ... to ...").
The activities are given this grouping value in a table called civicrm_option_value.

So I suppose I have to include some filter into the file /civicrm/CRM/Case/Form/CaseView.php, accessing each activity's grouping and testing it for "system".
Can you give me any hint how I can access the activities' grouping value?

Thanks in advance,
emma

Comment: a non-dev CMS dependent option might be to achieve this part of your workflow via Drupal Views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I directly changed the `CRM_Case_BAO_Case::getCaseActivity` function instead of creating an extension.

Specifically, I changed this function's `$where` variable to:

```
    $where = "
            WHERE cca.case_id= %1
              AND ca.is_current_revision = 1
              AND cov.grouping = 'visible'";
```

Here, "cov" is the alias for the table `civicrm_option_value`. The alias is already predefined in the `$from` variable above.

I added the grouping value "visible" manually in the database to those activities that should be visible in the case view.

Comment: so long as you have a good solid process for managing this during upgrades. i might get one of our folk to extensionize this if they and some users deem it useful - thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4):

The function that is responsible to build the list of activities on case is `CRM_Case_BAO_Case::getCaseActivity()`. It is very difficult to alter the function via custom module/plugin/extension.

I would create an extension that would alter the page callback for '`civicrm/ajax/activity`' to custom function (eg `CRM_ExtName_Page_AJAX::getCaseActivity` using [hook_civicrm_alterMenu](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterMenu/) hook. Copy `CRM_Activity_Page_AJAX::getCaseActivity()` into your custom php file i.e `CRM_ExtName_Page_AJAX::getCaseActivity()` and change the line below line to your custom function which will basically copy paste of `CRM_Case_BAO_Case::getCaseActivity` function with change the where clause to include your conditions

```
$activities = CRM_Case_BAO_Case::getCaseActivity($caseID, $params, $contactID, $context, $userID);
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you, I will work myself into that!

Comment: I don't quite understand the "change the where clause to include your conditions" part, as the `CRM_Activity_Page_AJAX::getCaseActivity()` does not have a where clause. Can you tell me what exactly you mean by that?

Comment: I mean something like creating class https://gist.github.com/pradpnayak/c3152131f857ce2e80fcf79fa4df22be and changing the where clause in getCaseActivity() as per your needs

Answer (score 1):

I've posted almost [exactly the same question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35117/is-there-a-way-to-separate-audit-activities-from-real-actvitites-in-a-case) and got some pretty helpful answers.

Especially the extension mentioned [here](https://civicrm.org/blog/jamienovick/civicase-new-way-manage-cases-using-civicrm) seems to be really useful (I have not tried it yet, though).

Comment: Thank you! I'd prefer not to include the official new CiviCase extension, because I only want to change this very specific issue, and the rest should stay as it is. I may create a small extension only for this purpose myself.